# richSelect for ag-grid in Angular2 (bound to object arrays)

Tags: angular, ag-grid

when I try to use richSelect in angular 2 (ag-grid-ng2) i get the following warning:

> cellEditorFactory.js:53 ag-Grid: unable to find cellEditor

code:

```
    {
        headerName: "Type",
        field: "TYPE_ID",
        width: 120,
        editable: true,
        cellEditor: 'richSelect',
        cellEditorParams: {
            values: this.lookups['TYPE']
        }
    }
```

switching it to 'select' renders the simple select

Comment: Are you pulling in ag-grid-enterprise too? richSelect is an enterprise only feature

Comment: I am using ag-grid-ng2 .. as far as i can tell there is no ag-grid-ng2-enterprise ?

Comment: just pull in ag-grid-enteprise as a dependency, then in your parent component import it: import 'ag-grid-enterprise/main';

Comment: thanks!!! i get a message in my console " Your license for ag-Grid Enterprise is not valid - please contact ag-Grid support to obtain a valid license. "

Comment: but i see the richSelect working, so does that mean i can still try out enterprise features ? what's the limitation before getting a license ? I am still proof of concepting..

Comment: ag-grid-enterprise is not free - you can trial it but to use it you need to purchase a license. This warning will not however disable any of the grids functionality

Comment: great thanks so much!

Comment: good luck with it :-)

Comment: i love the grid! but it has been a bit uphill to get simple stuff working :) i've been worried about the enterprise functionality in ng2 so this really helps. 
do you know of any examples in angular2 for nested grids? I know it's a new feature

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128849/discussion-between-sean-landsman-and-sonic-soul).

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Seans help I was able to figure this out.

To use enterprise features in ag-grid-ng2 you can just import the namespace

```
import 'ag-grid-enterprise/main';
```

To bind to object array, you need to define cellRenderer and newValueHandler. cellRenderer to indicate which field to use in the dropdown, and newValueHandler to indicate what to return back to the cell

```
 {
    headerName: "Type",
    field: "TYPE_ID",
    width: 120,
    editable: true,
    cellEditor: 'richSelect',
    cellEditorParams: {
      cellRenderer: o => o.value.name, // use name property from underlying collection
      values: this.lookups['TYPE'],
      newValueHandler: p => p.data[p.colDef.field] = p.newValue.name
   }
 }
```

Comment: I am new for using ag-grid-enterprise with angular2.... so can you give some steps for it and what configuration required? .. I have just installed using npm install ag-grid-enterprise ... what next to do?